# How to show grandparent's sibling of target?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how to get the parent's sibling of the target.

I want that when button.btn is clicked toggleSlide tr.show-hide.

1. https://codepen.io/raion/pen/dybxmLK?editors=1111
2. https://codepen.io/raion/pen/dybxmLK

I could do that one by one with an ID. 
But I wanna know how to code just one function for every button just in case I need more than 20 or 30 buttons.

```
<table>
  <tr class="toggle">
    <td> <button class="btn">toggle1</button> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----1111------</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="toggle">
    <td> <button class="btn">toggle2</button> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----2222------</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

---

```
<table class="table1">
  <tr class="table1__row">
    <th>table 1 - th1 </th>
    <td>table 1 - td </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="table1__row">
    <th>table 1 - th2 </th>
    <td>

      <table class="table2">
        <tr class="table2__row toggle">
        <th> table 2 - th1</th>
          <td> <button class="btn">toggle1</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="show-hide">
          <th></th>
          <td>-----1111------</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table2__row toggle">
          <th> table 2 - th2 </th>
          <td> <button class="btn">toggle2</button> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="show-hide">
          <th></th>
          <td>-----2222------</td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(e.target).closest('.toggle').next('.show-hide').dostuff()`

Comment: `closest()` finds ancestors, `find()` finds descendants, `next()` gets the next sibiling, `prev()` gets the previous sibiling.  All of these methods are detailed in the API.  https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/eb0qda46/1/) (button in 2 tables)

I changed the jQuery code to listen for click events when clicking on the actual toggle itself.

Next, you were missing the show/hide style in your fiddle:

`.show-hide.active {
  display: table-row;;
}`

```js
$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".toggle").toggleClass("active")
})
```

```css
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

th, td {
  padding : 1em;
}

.table1__row > th {
  background : lemonchiffon;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table1__row > td {
  background : #DDD;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table2__row > th {

}
.show-hide {
   display: none;
}

.show-hide.active {
  display: table-row;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
  <tr class="table1__row">
    <th>table 1 - th1 </th>
    <td>table 1 - td </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="table1__row">
    <th>table 1 - th2 </th>
    <td>
      
      <table class="table2">
        <tr class="table2__row toggle">
        <th> table 2 - th1</th>
          <td> <button class="btn">toggle1</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="show-hide">
          <th></th>
          <td>-----1111------</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table2__row toggle">
          <th> table 2 - th2 </th>
          <td> <button class="btn">toggle2</button> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="show-hide">
          <th></th>
          <td>-----2222------</td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

nextUntil() is what you are after if there are more than one row. Or you just need next() if it is just going to be one row.

```js
$("table").on("click", ".toggle", function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".toggle").toggleClass("active")
})
```

```css
.show-hide {
  display: none;
}

.show-hide.active {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="toggle">
    <td> <button class="btn">toggle1</button> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----1111------</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="toggle">
    <td> <button class="btn">toggle2</button> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----2222------</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="toggle">
    <td> <button class="btn">toggle3</button> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----3a------</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----3b------</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="toggle">
    <td> <button class="btn">toggle4</button> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="show-hide">
    <td>-----4------</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is working perfectly. The problem is it's not working with https://codepen.io/raion/pen/dybxmLK this. Is it possible if the btn  in 2 tables?